# Laravel 6 steam auth - How to store?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Im trying to grab user information with this package: https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth
But im a completely noob to laravel atm.

How do I store the steamID64 in the Auth::user() field named 'steamid'

My following handling atm:

```
public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->steam->validate()) {
            $info = $this->steam->getSteamId();

            if (!is_null($info)) {
                //I should store the steamid64 inside the Auth::user() field named 'steamid'
                return redirect($this->redirectURL); // redirect to site
            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToSteam();
    }
```

I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Auth::user()->steamid = $info; Auth::user()->save();` you can also do it in one line `Auth::user()->update(['steamid' => $info]);`

Comment: @N69S Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to check if that is unique? As I dont want people to enter the same id, under other users. Only one allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `save()`:

```php
Auth::user()->steamid = $info;
Auth::user()->save();
```

or using `update()`

```php
Auth::user()->update(['steamid' => $info]);
```

To check if the steamid already exists in your database:

```php
$isAlreadyPresent = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->where('steamid', '=', $info)->count();
```

if `$isAlreadyPresent` is zero then you dont have the steamid in the database or it's the current user steamid.